# Can location.pathname lead to XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript, dom

```
<div id="cat"></div>
<script>
$("#cat").html(location.pathname);
</script>
```

I think that example would work, but anyway, if location.pathname has to be a valid page, can this be exploited?

Edit: I'm mainly talking about if the user can't make up their own pathname, (i.e. `/test/<script>alert(0)</script>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if a path containing script tags is resolved to the page containing this code on your server (for example, via a rewrite rule) then script could be rendered in your page. This will be DOM based XSS as it will be your client-side code that is adding the script tag.

e.g. `https://www.example.com/foo/bar/<script>alert('foo')</script>`

Comment: Thank you. Is the only way it could be exploited if it allows the .htaccess rewrite rule? What if the javascript was contained in /example/example.html only?

Comment: @MichaelBlake: Depends on the tech stack - anything on the web server, load balancer, etc, that allows a URL containing script tags to resolve to the page could trigger the XSS.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought. I was just making sure there was no creative way for an attacker to stay on current page, but add their attack, that'd be carried to location.pathname (if that makes sense).

Comment: @MichaelBlake: A more secure way is to use `text` rather than `html` rather than rely on this as a security measure.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and allow anyone else to add any input, then I'll mark this as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I think @SilverlightFox is right here. Even if there is no rewrite in place at the moment, you don't want to have a site that could suddenly become vulnerable just because someone changes the server conf. That is dangerous.